# Cannot upload application to Tomcat7 on Ubuntu

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu, upload, tomcat7, file-permissions

I am trying to connect to a Ubuntu server I set up with FileZilla. My test server has the aptitude version of Tomcat7 as I have been advised to stick with Ubuntu packages for security. Tomcat is locked for user and owner `tomcat7:tomcat7` with prevention on writing to the webapp directory. Will adding myself to the tomcat7 group remedy this? as I can't upload webapps to this directory when I log in over Filezilla with my admin account. What is the correct methodology for doing this? I can't add myself to the tomcat 7 group using `sudo useradd - a -G tomcat7 myname` group even though I am the sole user and admin on this machine. What is the correct command to use?

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'm using on ubuntu 12.10 is using symlinks (with tomcat7 installed using apt-get).

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/myapps/mywebapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war ./mywebapp.war
```

It works and it is easy to deploy using scripts. After that I update sym linked war file using scp script on my dev workstation, and tomcat pick the changed war file and redeploy it. If you want atomic update, just add a new symlink intermediate, and update symlink after upload process.